# How to insert the values in google spreadheet in android

Tags: android

I have created a google spreadsheet by an android app. Now, I want to enter the values in that spreadsheet by an android app.

Comment: Its all [Documented](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android) here i guess .

Comment: Detail - I want to enter the data in sheet using text fields

Comment: And How to create the table headings in that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the app in android webview and then input the values manually.

here's the snippet for webview

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
  String url="Google spreadsheet url here";

    initWebView();

    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

with the right **url** it will open the spreadsheet, now you may do whatever you want!

> PS- if this does not answer your question please be more specific.